# Как сделать автодополнение ваеденого текста в боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Нашел статью, но не понимаю как реализовали и реализовать автодополнение текста (посмотрел апи бота, там нет таких функций)
[пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl3SZ.jpg)
Читал описание апи, как я понял, сделано как-то дополняются глобальные команды бота, а потом удаляются..

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: используют специальный сервис, который из текста генерирует реальный адрес. потом это отправлют пользователю. в чем сложности?